# Swift - Delay for dragging sknode

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, drag-and-drop, uigesturerecognizer, skspritenode

My SceneKit app has both

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
...
}

@objc func handleButtonMovement(recognizer : UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
...
}
```

The `SKSpriteNode` when touched doesn't trigger the `handleButtonMovement` unless you move slightly in any direction - but TouchesBegan is launched.

Also, if I touch the `SKSpriteNode` and move too quickly, the `handleButtonMovement` isn't triggered either.

Is there some way to adjust the sensitivity so that as soon as you touch the `SKSpriteNode`, it triggers `handleButtonMovement` as a drag event?

Comment: what is your goal here? do you wish to touch a sprite and trigger touches began but then when you move while touching that sprite it moves that sprite with your finger?

Comment: `UIPanGestureRecognizer` is triggered by movement of a touch. please add a little information to understand what is the respond that you expect. A little more code would help.